# How to enable Dark Mode on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to enable Dark Mode on emulator (with Android API 28), but after I choose "Dark" Theme on emulator in Settings, 
[image]

nothing is changed, except of setting value:

[image]

Is it possible at all to enable Dark Mode on emulator?

Comment: The result of `getNightMode()` is always `MODE_NIGHT_NO`, but it's settable with `setNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES)`. Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 24):

Answer by [@AchrafAmil and @MihailFleytman](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232271/setting-android-10-dark-theme-on-and-off-with-adb-shell-how-to-do-it-without-r#comment317562_236549) on Android StackExchange.

No reboot/root required

```sh
adb shell "cmd uimode night yes"
adb shell "cmd uimode night no"
```

Answer (score 16):

According to Google

> Dark theme is available in Android 10 (API level 29) and higher.

For me, it was easier to install an emulator with API level 29.

It works like a charm.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Answer (score 11):

On Android 10 go to `Display` -> `Dark Theme` and switch the toogle, in order to activate that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to a `system dark theme` I achieved on 28 was only for the background of the apps menu (homepage screen) to be either light or dark. And I could only achieve that after I switched to setting "Automatic based on wallpaper", changing wallpaper to a dark, watch it change (see attachments). Then dark and light modes started working as if they were unlocked.

[Homescreen in mode dark api 28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWqz8.png)

[Homescreen in mode light api 28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo9Pf.png)

I'd say real system dark theme is only working as intended in preview Q and up. And ofc, apps developed to support dark theme will all the way down to 14.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question.  My app detected and applied dark mode fine on an Android 9.0 device, but even with "Dark" theme enabled in the 9.0 emulator, nothing happened, and I initially thought it was broken.

I don't know if the theme setting actually does anything for the earlier emulators, but, yes, the theme setting works as expected on an Android 10.0 emulator as indicated by the other answers.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to activate the battery saver?
If using an android simulator, dark mode will be active after battery saver is activated

I've tried on android simulator Nexus 5x API 28

So the steps are

1. Settings -> Display -> Advance -> Device Theme -> Select Dark
2. Activate Battery Saver (Settings -> Battery -> Battery Saver)

Thanks

Reference: [developer android dark theme](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme?authuser=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-2%3Fauthuser%3D1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-theme#4)